# No. of elements sorted after m passes of insertionsort?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, insertion-sort

I am learning algorithms and Insertion sort. While solving the quiz, I came across the questions:

```
In insertion sort, after M passes through the array, How many elements are in sorted order?
```

With my understanding, I wrote `M+1` as the answer. But that turned out to be wrong.

Actual answer is : `First M elements are in sorted order after M passes of insertion sort on the array.`

Why is this so? This is what I thought:

Say I/p array : `5, 4, 3, 2, 1` is given to insertion sort. Now, after each iteration, the result will look like:

`Initial Input ==> after 1st iteration ==> after 2nd ==> after 3rd ==> after 4th`

`[5, 4, 3, 2, 1] ==> [4, 5, 3, 2, 1] ==> [3, 4, 5, 2, 1] ==> [2, 3, 4, 5, 1] ==> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

Here say after 2nd Iteration, we get `[3, 4, 5, 2, 1]` In which, elements `3, 4, 5` are sorted. So, after 2 passes, 3 elements are sorted. So, why was the answer `M`?

I tried finding answer from the internet, but there are no reliable resources / no explanations given. What am I missing here?

Comment: I agree with you. Any sensible implementation of insertion sort will move the element at index 1 (the 4 in your example) on the first pass, resulting in two sorted elements after one pass. The person who wrote the quiz didn't think it through.

Comment: Insertion sort doesn't really make multiple "passes through the array", so who knows what the words "pass through the array" are really supposed to mean?

Comment: Insertion sort *may* make *multiple passes through **part of the ordered part** of the array* (one alternative to *linear search* being finding the insertion point by *binary search*). As the outcome with an ordered part of no item/key at all is predetermined, starting with a length of one is sane. More examples to try: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, `[5, 1, 2, 3, 4]`.